# Inheritance question in Python for Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

All - I am new to coding and currently learning Python and Selenium.

Situation: I would like to have the following statement saved in a file and then I would like to call them in an another file. Intention is, I see that these import statements are called again and again every time you want to create a new python file. So thought of declaring in one file and calling that file. However, this is like "beating the bush" as I will have to call them and again detail it out instead of just calling the functions.

Directory name: `import_selenium_import_funcs`
"fileA" file contains:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

"fileB" file contains:

```py
from import_selenium_import_funcs import fileA
driver = fileA.webdriver.Firefox()
```

Here ultimately, I am calling the import functions from other file and again have to declare the fileA.webdriver instead of just declaring `driver = webdriver.Firefox()`

For this I found that I can declare the following statement and call the webdriver directly like,

```py
from import_selenium_import_funcs.fileA import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

My thought process was to have all the import functions (if we have more than 5 or 6) under one file and instead of declaring again and again in each file, thinking if there is any easier way to call them.

Please excuse me if my question is silly but wanted to see if anyone has any thoughts on this.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well yeah, you can do that. Althought it might be harder for other developers to read:)

Also note, that you can import everything from "fileA" using `from import_selenium_import_funcs.fileA import *`

Comment: ahhh!! that * definitely helps :) thank you!